# Is there an alternative design pattern for the autocomplete UI interaction

Tags: ux-designer, autocomplete, android

I have a form in android mobile app which has 3 nested autocomplete each one will depends on the previous one for its value. But the customer wants something better than autocomplete. Since there are lots of items in each field and they don't have any logical order, I've no idea what to do. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your current UI?

Comment: Can you further describe the use case is. Is the form displayed on multiple screens (i.e. depending on answer a different screen is shown). Also, what is the ultimate goal of this user flow?

Comment: the App  is for Paints Purchasing Orders
each order can has multi Items and each item has 3 auto complete attributes: color family , color code , packaging
the possible values of each filed depends on the selection of the previous field for each item.

Comment: In autocomplete you don't see the huge number of items and their order, right? Since you're seeing only the items that match? Could you explain the problem a little better?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to the UXSE pool of knowledge! Screen shot(s) of your application (or a mockup of it) is probably the best way to explain your use case, and also it is important to explain or understand why the customer does not autocomplete (is this an assumption or has it been tested?) so the best response from the community can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing more about the specific use-case, consider your data.

Good UX is all about providing the clearest and simplest way to get the minimum data required to do the job to the user's specifications.

You said in your comment that you've got Color Family, Color Code and Packaging and this is a loop you'll need to run through quickly for multiple products in the same order.

A brief googling (because of my own lack of familiarity with the terms Family and Code in this context) cleaned it up in my head and explained why Color code is causing you problems.

Your ideal case I believe is to have the colours visible on-screen to select, with Secondary data like the name and color code visible as well.

[Benjamin Moore](https://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-ca/colour-overview/find-your-colour/colour-families/yel/yellow?source=%2Fen-ca%2Fcolour-overview%2Ffind-your-colour%2Fcolour-families) has a good example of what I'm thinking of.

You simply select the family you want from a grid, then you're presented with a sub-grid of the different colours with the codes associated with them, select it and you see more data like the name and ultimately an option to purchase, where you get the price and volume/packaging option.

It's a simple visible hierarchy and it doesn't use drop-downs or autocomplete anywhere. You can also readily adapt it to whatever format you may like. for example a colour-wheel instead of the initial Family Grid.

Comment: +1 I like the answer to the question and hopefully we'll get a screen shot from the original poster of the question to clarify the requirements. A screenshot of your design pattern would also make your answer even better :)

Comment: @Ruadhan2300  thanks for ur detailed answer. unforuntally I can not use colors grid since the user of the apps wont purchase based on colors but based on the code since the users are professionals who know what paint they want to purchase

Comment: Well if they already know what paint they want to purchase by code..let them type in the code and then just for certitude, display the colour data before they confirm the choice. They shouldn't need the Family field at all in this case either.